# Get data from the Coroutines Flow

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

I am observing changes in the network and when there is connection I want to get the data from the Room database.

I have getOfflineData which returns a flow of data.

```
 @Query("SELECT * FROM OfflineData")
    fun getOfflineData(): Flow<List<OfflineData>>
```

When there is network connection I want to get the data from getOfflineData.

This is the function which checks if there is connection which works fine

```
fun listenToConnectionChanges() {
    launch {
        OfflineDatabaseManager.getInstance(app.applicationContext).networkConnectionActivated
            .collect { isNetworkConnectionActive ->
                Timber.d("OfflineDataLib - getOfflineData() - isNetworkConnectionActive - " + isNetworkConnectionActive)

            }
    }
}
```

when I included bellow code to get the data from the function getOfflineData(), it does not log the connection change message when i toggle connection. nor it gets the data.

I might be doing something fundamentally wrong here, please correct me

```
 fun listenToConnectionChanges() {
        launch {
            OfflineDatabaseManager.getInstance(app.applicationContext).networkConnectionActivated
                .collect { isNetworkConnectionActive ->
                    Timber.d("OfflineDataLib - getOfflineData() - isNetworkConnectionActive - " + isNetworkConnectionActive)
                    if (isNetworkConnectionActive) {
                        OfflineDatabaseManager.getInstance(app.applicationContext).getOfflineData().collect {
                            Timber.d("OfflineDataLib - getOfflineData() - isNetworkConnectionActive -  offlinedata - " + it.toString())
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

What I want to achieve is when there is connection, I want to get data from `getOfflineData`.

Thanks in advance
R

Comment: do you mean it dosnt not log this log  Timber.d("OfflineDataLib - getOfflineData() -....

Comment: hello, when network is active in function listenToConnectionChanges(), i want to get data from the data base

Comment: make sure that the flow callback dosnt return null values from room db , you can debug and if the log inside the flow callback is not executed , i guess the values are null

Answer (score 0):

You can't collect elements of a `Flow` (flow1) in the collect block of another `Flow` (flow2). The flow1 can be infinite and suspend the collect block of flow2 endlessly. For your purpose you can use [`flatMapLatest`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/flat-map-latest.html) function.

> `flatMapLatest` returns a flow that switches to a new flow produced by transform function every time the original flow emits a value.

The sample code will look like the following:

```
fun listenToConnectionChanges() {
    launch {
        OfflineDatabaseManager.getInstance(app.applicationContext).networkConnectionActivated
            .filter { it }
            .flatMapLatest { 
                // networkConnectionActivated will be always true here because we filter values
                OfflineDatabaseManager.getInstance(app.applicationContext).getOfflineData()
            }.collect {
                Timber.d("OfflineDataLib - getOfflineData() - isNetworkConnectionActive -  offlinedata - " + it.toString())
            }
    } 
}
```